# Build error Could not load file or assembly Microsoft.CodeAnalysis

Tags: linux, asp.net-core

We have a .net core 3.1 solution, which we are able to compile (using Visual Studio 2019) and publish.  We gave the solution to our team which is setting up the deployment process.  While trying the build (linux container) they are seeing the below error:

> CommonLib -> /srv/jenkins_work/DSS/ewcms/CMS/CommonLib/bin/release/netcoreapp3.1/CommonLib.dll
> CSC : error CS8032: An instance of analyzer Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.InternalUsageDiagnosticAnalyzer cannot be created from /var/lib/jenkins/.nuget/packages/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.analyzers/5.0.9/analyzers/dotnet/cs/Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Analyzers.dll : Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.CodeAnalysis, Version=3.7.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'. The system cannot find the file specified.. [/srv/jenkins_work/DSS/ewcms/CMS/Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.UnitOfWork/Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.UnitOfWork.csproj]

The file mentioned Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Analyzers.dll is there in the folder mentioned in the error.  other projects in the same solution have this as a warning, but this particular project shows it as an error.

Reading online many said to install Visual Studio, but that is something they said they can not do in the container, is there another way to get around this issue?  Or something in particular we need to look at in that project which is causing and error rather than a warning?

Comment: Hi @Paritosh, I think you could refer to [this github issue](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/23234).

Comment: @Rena spoke with our build team, they did not want to install .net 5, wanted to keep the container at .net core 3.1 only.

Answer (score 0):

After some investigation, turned out that project had the setting:

```
<TreatWarningsAsErrors>true</TreatWarningsAsErrors>
```

which was not there in the other projects, which were showing it as warnings only.  Changed this to false and this project is also going through now, it comes up as a warning and allows the build to go through.